# In org-mode how to break current section and escape to upper level

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

In org-mode, normal hierarchy goes like :

```
* Section 1
  Content of section 1

  ** Section 1-1
     Content of section 1-1

  ** Section 1-2
     Content of section 1-2
```

As I understand it, everything after a header belongs to that section until it meets another (higher or lower) header.

But is it possible to break the current section without using another header, and to continue the content of the previous section? Something like :

```
* Section 1
  Content of section 1

  ** Section 1-1
     Content of section 1-1
  ** Section 1-1 end

  Content of section 1 continues ...

  ** Section 1-2
     Content of section 1-2
  ** Section 1-2 ends


  Content of section 1 continues ...
```

Comment: * or ** are  start  markers.  You see that we don't have end-marker defined unlike programming code blocks. "()" or { }.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There has been a [long discussion](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/40182) in org-mode mailing list on this same issue.

Several proposals, but at the end, the need for simplicity and compatibility with LaTeX, DocBook and traditional book/article structures seem more important than allowing for content continuation after subheadings.

Also, content continuation after subheading sections end is in general not obvious to the reader.

One of the workarounds proposed is using lists as the sub-content. This is quite clear in the markup, and also for the reader.

Comment: What if I just want to move a `# Local Variables: ...` section at the bottom all the way to the left margin?